# GET http://localhost:3000/images ERROR 404 not found

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tengo un problema con rendizar una imagen con vuejs. Tengo una base de datos con mongodb. Cuando creo una artículo, todo funciona bien. Me guarda la imagen en la en la base de datos

```
imageUrl:"http://localhost:3000/images/nombre.jpeg".
```

En la carpeta que le toca, `"assets/images"` como siempre. Hasta ahora iba bien así.

Pero ahora en este proyecto cuando hago mi `request get` me sale

```
http://localhost:3000/images/nombre.jpeg" error 404 not found.
```

lo mismo con `http://localhost:3000/assets/images/nombre.jpeg`

Por el frontend uso: vuejs and axios.

No sé por dónde buscar.

Si alguien tiene una idea o una pista ?
Muchas gracias

Comment: En la carpeta donde se ejecuta tu proyecto, ¿tienes una carpeta llamada `assets/images` y dentro el archivo `nombre.jpeg` ?

Comment: Buenas noches 
fredyfx
 Si, del lado backend tengo mi carpeta con las imagenes. el servidor en el port 3000.

Comment: Tal cual está la pregunta y confirme dices en el comentario anterior, ¿sería mucho pedir que agregues todos los detalles posibles para reproducir tu escenario por favor?

Comment: Buenas tardes, solucionado el problema. No sé porque no lo pensé antes. Venia del servidor del backend uso Express. en mi configuraciòn del fichero app.js habia : app.use(express.static("images")); cuando tenia que ser app.use(express.static("assets")); donde se encontra mi carpeta images. De toda forma muchas gracias por su interes en arreglar problemas de otros, espero que un dia serà yo el ayudante.

Comment: Pues, eso se hubiera solucionado aún más rápido si hubieras puesto el código en la pregunta... Por otro lado, en la parte inferior dice "Tu Respuesta", coloca a detalle lo que hiciste. Saludos.